# Output field from another table on insert SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table `@p2` sent as parameter to a stored procedure that has an id named `IdObjectSubTypeTemp`, I need to insert in a table `ObjectSubType`and output the identity with the id of the parameter table as below:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ObjectSubType]
    ([IdObject]
    ,[IdSubType])
OUTPUT inserted.[IdObjectSubType] ,OS.[IdObjectSubTypeTemp]
INTO @IdObjectSubTypeTbl
SELECT OS.[IdObject] 
    ,OS.[IdSubType]
FROM @p2 OS
```

But I keep getting that:

> The multi-part identifier "OS.IdObjectSubTypeTemp" could not be bound.

although I did the same on update and it is working but on insert it's not working

Comment: `OS.IdObjectSubTypeTemp` is not in your select list

Comment: @Squirrel yes because i do not want to insert it in the table ObjectSubType i just want to output it

Comment: It's not necessary that all the columns should be listed in select but all should present in the from table so you can join with other table where this column is exit and simply add in the inserted not in the select in this this column will be saved in output table only.

Comment: @Susang the column does not exist in any physical table ... it only exists in the temp table `@p2` and i just want to map the column in the temp with the identity that is created but i can't add it in the physical table

Comment: @User7291 Are you using a case sensitive collation?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `MERGE` instead of `INSERT INTO`. It will allow to refer to @p2 columns, even if not used:

```
DECLARE @p2 AS TABLE (IdObject INT,IDSubType INT,IdObjectSubTypeTemp CHAR(10));
DECLARE @IdObjectSubTypeTbl AS TABLE (col1 INT, col2 CHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @p2(IdObject, IDSubType, IdObjectSubTypeTemp) VALUES(1,1,'a');

MERGE INTO [dbo].[ObjectSubType] tgt
USING @p2 src ON tgt.IdObject = src.IdObject
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT  (IdObject, IdSubType)
VALUES (src.IdObject, src.IdSubType)
OUTPUT inserted.[IdSubType] ,src.[IdObjectSubTypeTemp]   
                             -- refering to column not used in INSERT
INTO @IdObjectSubTypeTbl(col1, col2);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f25487be464c36a5a15049d5d1bd41bc)**

Comment: does `merge` have the same performance as `Insert` because as I know that the performance of the `Insert` is better..

Comment: @User7291 You should always compare execution plans before make any predictions. I would same it is comparable (please not that here I first check if value exists in target table, while with your insert approach you INSERT rows directly)

Answer (score 2):

The [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) does not support referencing the from_table_name when used in an INSERT statement - read the docs carefully, it's not very clear, see the comments too.

You could use the OUTPUT clause to capture the new identity value inserted.[IdObjectSubType] then a seperate query to INSERT [IdObjectSubType] and [IdObjectSubTypeTemp] INTO @IdObjectSubTypeTbl.

Comment: excerpt from the docs: *from_table_name*
Is a column prefix that specifies a table included in the FROM clause of a DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement that is used to specify the rows to update or delete. *Note how this excludes INSERT.*